# XAMPP Permission Denied for Require_Once Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: php, macos, apache, permission-denied, require-once

**Problem:**

I'm trying to open headerr.php via require_once on a XAMPP localhost server. I'm calling this function through index.php but I keep on receiving the following error message

**Errors:**

Warning: require_once(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Baseline/headerr.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Baseline/index.php on line 2

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'headerr.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php') in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Baseline/index.php on line 2

**Attempted Solutions:**

-I've tried setting the permissions to Read & Write for everyone on the (/Applications/XAMPP) Folder but that hasn't fixed the permissions issue.

-I've also tried using require_once dirname(**FILE**) . '/headerr.php'; but that didn't work either..

**In Conclusion:**

I suspect that I may have to edit the php.ini file but I have no clue what to do..
I appreciate any advice or insight, thanks!

Comment: Did you set read and write permissions *for the correct user* for *all the directories* in that path? If the top dir is readable but a middle dir isn't, the whole path is not accessible.

Comment: Where would I do this? I set the permissions for the XAMPP folder thru the finder by right clicking, selecting get info and changing the sharing & permissions

Comment: I could do the same for the following folders if that's what you're saying

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. You can go into Terminal and check the file permissions on any of the directories or file by typing `cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Baseline/` and then `ls -alF` to see the file permissions for the files in that folder. Do you know how to read file permissions on Mac (drwxrwxrwx etc)? Note the owner and the group owner (to the right of the owner) of the files. Either a) Apache needs to own the files or b) Apache needs to be a part of the group owner and group needs to have read/write.

Comment: So i changed the permissions to read & write for everyone on each folder mentioned in the above errors... but it still returns the same response. Is there somewhere on php.ini that might fix the permissions?

Comment: I don't know about drwxrwxrwx permissions but I entered those commands in terminal and it only displays my name michaelmontalban and admin to the right of my name for every item in the folder

Comment: So.. you need to find out what user/group Apache runs as in XAMPP. Look for a httpd.conf file which will have that information. Then you'll need to either change the owner of the file to whatever user Apache runs as or add Apache to the admin group, or change the group owner to something else and add both Apache and yourself to that group or change which user/group Apache runs as. The safest is to add both yourself and Apache to a different group and deny access to everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
chmod -R 775 yourWebFolder
```